# How number of votes increase on questions with multiple tags?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, tags

Let's say I gave an answer on a question that have the following tags: [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css). Now my answer gets an upvote. What will happen to number of upvotes of both the tags? Will only one will get increased or the upvotes will be divided or each will get all the upvotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your score for tags "html" and "css" shall get incremented by one each. If there were any more tags for the question, all of those will be incremented by one each as well.

Although, it takes sometime before your "tag-score" for the tags gets updated. I think the duration for updates is about 3 or 5 hours. Not sure about exact time.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I was before :)